# How to restrict input text box allow only 0 and 1

Tags: jquery, binary

I want to allow user to type only 0 and 1 in  input field in both pc and mobile browser  that is binary value i am having the following code

```
<input class="binaryOnly" size="8" maxlength="6" id="tese" type="text" />
```

please guide me to achieve this using jquery

Comment: type = number. min = 0, max =  1.

Comment: input type is only text type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A native JS example:

```js
document.getElementById('tese').addEventListener('keydown', function(ev) {
  if(ev.keyCode != 48 && ev.keyCode != 49 && ev.keyCode != 8) {
    ev.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

```html
<input class="binaryOnly" size="8" maxlength="6" id="tese" type="text" />
```

Comment: Yes. But ES2015 style coding has less mobile support so I edited the answer to remove the fat arrow.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in Jquery:

```
$(function(){
  $('#txt').keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 48 || e.which == 49 || e.which == 8)  // 8 is for backspace
    {
      // Do something here
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/migahulute/edit?html,css,js,output)

Comment: its working fine in pc what about the mobile browser

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
    $('#tese').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.which == 48 || e.which == 49 || e.which == 8)return;
        else return false; 
    });
});
```